# Entity Framework many-to-many relationship between 3 tables

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core

I have 3 tables `Groups`, `Roles` & `ResourceGroup`. They have many-to-many relations using another table. One group can have many roles in one `ResourceGroup` and can have the same/different roles in another `ResourceGroup`.

Also the same role can belong to many groups in the same or different `ResourceGroup`.

I couldn't find any way to design it using Entity Framework code-first approach. The ER diagram is posted here:

[image]

Comment: Try doing it by reverse engineering with scaffolding and see how EF does the mapping?

Comment: You simply have a class, `ResourcePolicy`, that has three 1:n relationships to other classes. Don't think of it as many-to-many.